# Select based on another select from few tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I am trying to do the following query:

1. SELECT family_id from table lamps based on lamp_id
2. SELECT family_parents from table lamps_family based on family_id from 1.
3. SELECT lamps from table lamps based on family_id which i get from 2.

TL;DR

I would like to use a single query to get all the lamps based on the ID of the family, but there are several families assigned to one parent. For example, in the table "lamps_family" there are two families that have "parent" with id 11, it's about "Asseto". Now based on "family_id" I would like to download all the lamps from the table "lamps" by asking the field "lamp_family" in the table "lamps. Is it possible?

I tried to combine tables, use grouping, unfortunately without success.
[table lamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c9i3.jpg)

[table lamps_family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SKf2.jpg)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Look into inner and/or left joins.  If you post tables without images we can help better

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: Please make it easy to help you by posting sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your lamp ID is 21 (Asseto).

```
SELECT lamps.* FROM lamps
  JOIN lamps_family ON lamps.lamp_family = lamps_family.family_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT lamps_family.family_id FROM lamps JOIN lamps_family ON
      lamps.lamp_family = lamps_family.family_id
      WHERE lamps.id = 21
    ) lamp ON lamp.family_id = lamps_family.family_id
```

That should work?

First you create the full data set that joins all lamp data to the lamps_family metadata and use another join (kinda a self-join) to filter to a specific lamp's metadata.